# OpenErp(Odoo) How to add custom analysis on reporting Tab

Tags: odoo, reporting

I need to make **summery** of raw materials used, the qualty of products ,final products status  . . . **for each  manufactureing process** and provide this information **on the reporing tab** like sales anlysis and purchase analysis . . . How can I do this? and insights about my requirment?

Answer (score 0):

Create a module for your custom analysis report. I will explain how the Sales Analysis report is created. Using that you could create your own analysis report.

**Steps**

1. Create a module for your report in the `addons` folder. You can use the following link for details about creating a module [How to create an ODOO module](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html)
2. Create a python file in the module and import it in the `__init__.py` file. In that file create a model based on a `PostgreSQL view`. Add a method `init(self, cr)` that creates a `PostgreSQL View` matching the fields declared in `_columns`. You can check this in the file `sale_report.py` in report folder of sale module. Create the fields you needed in the `_columns` and write the query in the `init` method for getting values to these fields.

   Specify the parameter `_auto=False` to the OpenERP object, so no table corresponding to the `_columns` dictionary is created automatically.

   For the model `sale.report` data is taken from a view defined in the `init` method of the model. The value for each field is calculated dynamically, that is at the time we click on the `menuitem` for the Sales Analysis report in Reporting tab. The aliases in the `select` query of the view creation are the field names of the model `sale_report`. For example in `select` query you can find `uom_id` as `product_uom` where `product_uom` is column in the model `sale_report`.
3. Define the views. Create an XML file in the report folder of the module. You can use the `sale_report_view.xml` file in the `sale` module as reference. Create an XML view for the model, including `tree view, search view and graph view`. In the tree view, there is an attribute in the `<tree>` tag that is `create="false"`. This is used  for hiding the `create` button in the `tree view`. Create an `action` and a `menuitem` for the view as in the sales analysis report.
4. Restart the server and upgrade the module.

Compare your report with sales analysis reportto solve any issues.

Comment: sir, How about in Odoo8?